# Add image, after long space in begin environment [Title changeable]

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}

\newcommand{\rect}[2]{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,pad at break=1mm,]{#1}
\textit{\begin{flushright}{#2}\end{flushright}}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\rect{Picture is
\begin{center}\shorthandoff{=}
\includegraphics{cap.pdf}
\end{center}}{capacitor.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: why not `\includegraphics{cap.pdf}\vspace{-1cm}`?

Comment: @Pouya, it is working.

Comment: What about changing to `\begin{flushright}\textit{#2}\end{flushright}` instead of `\textit{\begin{flushright}{#2}\end{flushright}}`. That will reduce some vertical space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this, there is no space. But this is not the way to define a wrapper box. But since I don't know exactly what you want, I can't make it better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}

\newcommand{\rect}[2]{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm,colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,pad at break=1mm,]
#1\par\raggedleft \textit{#2}\end{tcolorbox}}

\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{document}

\rect{Picture is
\begingroup\par\centering
\includegraphics{logo}
\par
\endgroup
}{capacitor.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\newtcbox`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes why not? That is what I told in the second sentence `;-)`